# ASP .NET Boilerplate Swagger XML documentation for Controllers not visible

Tags: api, asp.net-core, swagger-ui, aspnetboilerplate, swagger-codegen

I created an Angular SPA Project using the asp boilerplate template and added a summary to the implementation of the controller for a sample function as suggested in [this issue](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3285).

```
/// <summary>
/// This is my sample function
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public Task SummaryTestMethod()
{
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

However, the swagger UI does not seem to register my remarks. I have not changed any other part in the code so far. Shouldn't the default configuration include the remarks? What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the steps:

1.Enable the creation of XML documentation.In the **Solution Explorer**, right-click the project and click **Properties**. Click the **Build** tab and navigate to **Output**. Make sure that the **XML documentation file** option is checked. You can leave the default file path:

[image]

2.You need to make some changes to our Startup.cs file to tell swagger to use those comments:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    //1.locate the xml file being generated
    //if you choose the default file path in the first step,
    //the file name is SolutionName.xml
    //the file path is the project path
    var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name}.XML";
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);

    //2.tell swagger to use those xml comments
    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    //...
}
```

Result:

[image]

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments

Comment: Hi @atpekbas,Did my answer help you resolve your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. On a solution with one project, it works. But, since I'm working with the abp boilerplate template, the application and the web host layers are separate. I can't seem to be able to connect the application layer xml to the swagger running in the web host.